# Going through divorce - irrational behavior

Tags: nikah, talaq

Salam,

unfortunately the wife (non Muslim but of the book) and I are divorcing. Her behavior is very irrational and makes no sense with anything she is doing and saying. I am very calm and cool but she always swears at me and yells and threatens to call the police when I am just going to the apartment to even grab a couple of my things.

Her parents drove down from 2 hours away to help her pack but no one has heard my side of anything and nothing makes sense. She has deliberately been causing friction and misconstruing everything I say no matter how best I say it. Her behavior is very childish and immature but I wish there was a way to just talk to her.

She also stole $10K of my money without telling me and nothing can be done about it, then she withdrew some money yesterday (I did open another account and transfer money into it)

almost 2 years been married and I have paid for EVERYTHING and did everything I could but she does not get it or see it or appreciate it, but acts in this horrid and uncomfortable way - every day I am on eggshells.

I keep praying to Allah but nothing. And she also knows I only have a very short time left to be in the country (we are not filing any paperwork for immigration so this has nothing to do with it) and she is just taking advantage of everything.

Something has got to her/possessed her. She is dramatic and overreacts unnecessarily.

What can I do? What prayers and dua's can I recite for this situation to be smoothed over and for me to not have any penalty against me during the divorce in terms of finances? But importantly for her to see that she is wrong. I understand it is too late but still, I feel like just holding her (but cannot, and will not) and telling her to talk as *I* always talk and try to make her see sense but the last week, not much at all.

I am in a temporary safe accommodation but I need to find another place to stay as I cannot even go to my own apartment because of her. I work from home most of the time so this is affecting my work and income too.

I have always wanted peace but I get a lot of hostility. No one seems to listen from my side or even simply ask what is going on. It is all her side.

Please, help. Allah SWT is of course who I turn too but I feel like he is not listening or I have done something wrong and I still repent if I have done something wrong.

Honestly, her conduct is very unreasonable and belligerent, as my attorney has also said. I don't want to file a protection order against her because I am not like this but it seems I may have to do this very soon.

Answer (score 1):

Subhaanallah my dear brother. May Allah swt grant you success and make your affairs easy insha Allah. As to what you said on your question pertaining on what to do, a simple answer, as this goes to myself firstly. Never lose hope in Allah swt. At times it seems like our supplications are not answered, but Allah swt is Samee'un-Aleem(hearer&knower of all things. There's a Qur'anic verse that says: verily your wealth, belongings and children will be a test for you.) You should ask Allah swt to make you stand firm in this test, so that you may overcome it by Allah's assistance. There's plenty of adiyah to recite for different calamities etc but the main objective here is not to lose hope and think your prayers are not answered. Remember!!! Allah swt loves those who are patient even though they're being tested. I will make dua for you my brother. Shukran